# HTML 5 video volumne/muted issue

Tags: javascript, html, video

this is my video:

```
<video id="video1" autoplay="true" muted="true">
    <source src="videos/test.mp4v" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If I removed the muted attribute, there is no sound!  I don't know why. BUT what I want t achieve is when i press a button I want to unmuted my video.
This is my js code:

```
$(".play-pause").click(function(){
        $("#video1").prop("volume", 0.5);
        $("#video1").prop("muted", false);
});
```

So, first question why my video is muted by default ?
Second question how do I unmuted my video when i press a button ?
Thx a lot !

Comment: 1st : when no value value is assigned to the `muted` attribute, the value is assigned to `true`, like for any other attribute (`autoplay`, `controls`...). 2nd : try with `attr()` method instead ?

Comment: I tried with attribute, still the same, no sound. I check with firebug and i have the attribute muted="false"

Comment: can't repro http://jsfiddle.net/tn4h7wf0/

Comment: FOR SOME REASON ON CHROME ITS WORKING THERE IS SOUND, in mozilla NOT , WHY ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#play-pause").click( function (){
    if( $("#video1").prop('muted') )
    {
        $("#video1").prop('muted', false);
        $("#video1").prop("volume", 0.5);
    }

   else {
    $("#video1").prop('muted', true);
    }

});});
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the mute by default, just erase the "muted" attribute from the video tag.
To set the volume, put this inside your function:

```
var vid1 = $("video");
vid1.volume = 0.5;
```